# trying to overwrite 'file', which is also in package '*', how to solve?

Tags: dpkg

I'm not able to update anything. I'm on 13.10.

When I try to install updates I get this:

```
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/librhythmbox-core7_3.0.1-0~13.10~ppa1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/librhythmbox-core.so.8.0.0', which is also in package librhythmbox-core8 3.0.1-1ubuntu5~ppa0
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/librhythmbox-core7_3.0.1-0~13.10~ppa1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Does anyone have a solution ?

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy librhythmbox-core7 librhythmbox-core8`.

Comment: TY. I did that. Im still getting this
Error occured. 
E: /var/cache/apt/archives/librhythmbox-core7_3.0.1-0~13.10~ppa1_amd64.deb: trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/librhythmbox-core.so.8.0.0', which is also in package librhythmbox-core8 3.0.1-1ubuntu5~ppa0

Comment: Ok, seems that we got a language problem. You run the command, edit the question, copy the output of the command and paste it in the question.

Comment: I ran the command and that was my output

Comment: librhythmbox-core7:
  Installed: 2.99.1-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 3.0.1-0~13.10~ppa1
  Version table:
     3.0.1-0~13.10~ppa1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jacob/media/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2.99.1-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
librhythmbox-core8:
  Installed: 3.0.1-1ubuntu5~ppa0
  Candidate: 3.0.1-1ubuntu5~ppa0
  Version table:
 *** 3.0.1-1ubuntu5~ppa0 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jacob/media/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: sorry that was the ouput

Comment: Could you [edit] the question and add it.?

Answer (score 8):

The problem is because the package is trying to override `/usr/lib/librhythmbox-core.so.8.0.0` which is provided by another package.

`librhythmbox-core7` is installed on your system, and you're trying to install `librhythmbox-core8`.

You need to manually remove `librhythmbox-core7` before you can install `librhythmbox-core8`.

```
sudo dpkg --remove librhythmbox-core7
sudo apt-get install librhythmbox-core8
```

Also, inform the package maintainer about this.

Comment: @jospeh Royce: If Bozolino's answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.