# Xubuntu package broken : conflict between Open Office en Libreoffice

Tags: package-management

I use Open Office software, version 4.0.1 on a Xubuntu system.

Since I tried to install also the `libreOffice-writer` on the system:

- The system package of Xubuntu is broken.
- It is not possible any more to uninstall Open Office or uninstall `libreoffice-writer`, finally to reinstall Open Office and get rid of Libreoffice.
- It is not possible any more to download any software at all on the PC.

Every time I try to repair the xubuntu package, Xubuntu asks me to reinstall `libreoffice-common`. But when I try to install it, it does not succeed. An error is displayed.

On the internet I have seen that OpenOffice and LibreOffice both use the same files. 
That is the reason both software packages conflict with each other.

Can anyone tell me what I should do to get out of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I figured the solution out. After being asked to install libreoffice-common, I ran "sudo apt-get install -f" and then "sudo apt-get -f install," finding a line in there somewhere that said "trying to overwrite ... which is also in package ..." I manually removed the package that was preventing the install using the directions found here ([trying to overwrite 'file', which is also in package '*', how to solve?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/389549/trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in-package-how-to-solve)). After that, I was able to install the other package that I wasn't able to before, and everything cleared up.